# Could not dispatch event: class android.widget.RelativeLayout to handler

Tags: android, android-widget, android-maps-v2

I am working with Google Android Maps 2. The map can be viewed without any trouble, if I save a location and if when I select this location in the startup screen (which just lists the saved location by name) the application breaks and the following exception is raised:

```
ERROR/Android Runtime(5778): Couldn't get connection factory client : main java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event: class android.widget.RelativeLayout to handler
```

It should show the map center-ed to the selected location. I have checked all the location data being passed on properly even the layout which is used to view the result works properly when used to view the map if no location is saved previously.

Anybody has any clue on what to look into when this error occurs.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Now spending a lot of time on this, finally figured out the problem.

The problem occurred when I set the cameraposition using animateCamera(LatLngBounds, Padding).

The LatLngBounds could not be set directly, so I had to use

`animateCamera(LatLngBounds, width, height, padding)`

Thanks all for viewing.